# How to display hl7 code in MS-Word with its format

Tags: ms-word, format, hl7

I want to paste HL7 code with its format from the Hapi Test Panel but I don't know how, does anyone can help me?

[image]

Here it is the code:

> MSH|^~\&|NES|NINTENDO|TESTSYSTEM|TESTFACILITY|20010101000000||ADT^A04|Q123456789T123456789X123456|P|2.3
>   EVN|A04|20010101000000|||^KOOPA^BOWSER^^^^^^^CURRENT
>   PID|1||123456789|012345678 
>   9^AA^^JP|BROS^MARIO||19850101000000|M|||123 FAKE STREET^MARIO \T\
>   LUIGI BROS PLACE^TOADSTOOL
>   KINGDOM^NES^A1B2C3^JP^HOME^^1234|1234|(555)555-0123^HOME^JP:1234567|||S|MSH|12345678|||||||0|||||N
>   NK1|1|PEACH^PRINCESS|SO|ANOTHER CASTLE^^TOADSTOOL
>   KINGDOM^NES^^JP|(123)555-1234|(123)555-2345|NOK
>   NK1|2|TOADSTOOL^PRINCESS|SO|YET ANOTHER CASTLE^^TOADSTOOL
>   KINGDOM^NES^^JP|(123)555-3456|(123)555-4567|EMC
>   PV1|1|O|ABCD^EFGH||||123456^DINO^YOSHI^^^^^^MSRM^CURRENT^^^NEIGHBOURHOOD
>   DR NBR|^DOG^DUCKH 
>   UNT^^^^^^^CURRENT||CRD|||||||123456^DINO^YOSHI^^^^^^MSRM^CURRENT^^^NEIGHBOURHOOD
>   DR NBR|AO|0123456789|1|||||||||||||||||||MSH||A|||20010101000000
>   IN1|1|PAR^PARENT||||LUIGI IN1|2|FRI^FRIEND||||PRINCESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [colouriser on HAPI homepage](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/colouriser.html). I have copied the formatted text from there to MS Word without any problems.